# How to find out who manages the Facebook Business Manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-business-manager

When trying to update the WhatsApp number of a page I manage, I'm faced with:

> You must be an admin in Facebook Business Manager to confirm a WhatsApp account

I'm an admin of this Facebook page. How do I find out manages the Facebook Business Manager that had claimed this page?

I'm even struggling with identifying the Facebook Business Manager account itself.

Answer (score -1):

It's Zahid a digital marketing expert here. You can check which business manager associated to your business page. You need to go to your facebook business page settings option. Then you need to go to Page Role option. You can see details there. If you need any help you can let me know.
Thanks

Comment: There are multiple admins and a single Page owner which is a business. Now what?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).